# How do I style the default identity pages in an ASP.NET React JS application?

Tags: css, reactjs, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0

I have created an ASP.NET React JS web application (.NET 7.0), using individual user accounts. I have then used the identity scaffold to add in the identity .cshtml pages into the 'Areas' folder.

I simply want to style the default identity pages, which I tried to do by adding in a css file `Register.css` into `wwwroot/css`. I have then tried referencing this file from `Register.cshtml`, both in the Register and layout pages like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/Register.css" />
```

I have also tried referencing it as `/css/Register.css`.

When I run my application and go to the register page, when I go to the dev tools I can see the css file does appear in the sources under localhost > css > Register.css. However the contents of the file are those of the `index.html` file in the `ClientApp` folder.

When running the application it first goes to port 7000 something and then redirects to port 44000 something once the SPA proxy is ready. If I manually browse to `localhost:7000/css/Register.css` I am able to see the correct contents of the css file.

The contents of my `Program.cs` file currently are as follows, which is close to the default:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/src";
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Similarly the contents of my `setupProxy.js` file are as follows:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
    env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:54720';

const context = [
    "/weatherforecast",
    "/_configuration",
    "/.well-known",
    "/Identity",
    "/connect",
    "/ApplyDatabaseMigrations",
    "/_framework",
    "/signin-microsoft",
    "/signin-google",
    "/Identity/manage"
];

module.exports = function (app) {
    const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
        target: target,
        secure: false,
        headers: {
            Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
        }
    });

    app.use(appProxy);
};
```

I've tried a few different things to fix this:

- Referencing the css file using absolute and relative paths
- Setting the build action to 'copy always'
- Changing the `launchsettings.json` to try and go straight to port 44000 but this results in a continual redirect loop (as expected)
- Changing around some settings in `setupProxy.js` which also resulted in redirection issues
- Changing `app.UseStaticFiles` in `Program.cs` to allow unknown file types in case it was an issue with that

I was expecting that my `Register.css` file would appear in the sources in the dev tools, but it is currently showing the contents of my `index.html` file from the `ClientApp` folder.

I'm not sure where to go from here really, as this is a newly created application which I expected would be simple enough to style the identity pages. Please let me know if I need to add any further information.